# How can I change this curl command into a python request command?

Tags: curl, python-requests

This command uploads a file to HDFS.

```
➜  ~ curl -L -i -X PUT -T ./to_be_uploaded.py -H 'Authorization: Basic BASE64ENCODED' "https://SERVER/webhdfs/v1/user/USERNAME/uploaded.py?op=CREATE"
```

I want to change this command into a request command, as below:

```
base_url = "https://SERVER/webhdfs/v1/user/USERNAME/"
m_url = base_url + FILENAME
headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic BASE64ENCODED'}
# Some more lines
r = requests.put(url = m_url, headers = headers, SOMETHING...}
```

I'm having trouble adding `?op=CREATE` and `-T ./to_be_uploaded.py`

When I just do

```
data = {'op':'CREATE'}
r = requests.put(url=m_url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
```

This error occurs.

```
'op=NULL is not supported'
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need something like this:

```
import requests

url = "https://SERVER/webhdfs/v1/user/USERNAME/uploaded.py?op=CREATE"

payload = {}
files = [
  ('files', open('<image path>/<image name>.jpg','rb'))
]
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer <your token>'
}

response = requests.request("PUT", url, headers=headers, data = payload, files = files)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

---

Updated

Regarding the URL, you could use the urllib and a dictionary

```
import urllib

getVars = {'op': 'CREATE'}
url = 'https://SERVER/webhdfs/v1/user/USERNAME/uploaded.py?'
print(url + urllib.urlencode(getVars))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just wonder if there's any way that I can separate `op=CREATE` from the url. And could you share a link of related document? I read https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request and I couldn't find what I want.

Comment: Here you go https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode